# WHERE on a SELECT sub-query

Tags: sql

Here is a table

```
--------------------
|   Id    |   Val  |
|---------|--------|
|   1     |   4    |
|   2     |   3    |
|   3     |   5    |
|   4     |   1    |
--------------------
```

I need a query like

```
SELECT * , 
CASE 
 WHEN val > 3 THEN 'PASS' 
 ELSE 'FAIL' 
END as Status
FROM StatusTable
WHERE Status = 'PASS'
```

But, it doesn't seem to work that way.
here is the error:

`Uncaught Error: near "when": syntax error`

Please help me with a workaround.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `WHERE val > 3`. In MySQL you may use `HAVING Status = 'PASS'`, not in WHERE.

Comment: your query is missing a `FROM <table name>`. Apart from that, we have no idea what do you want.

Comment: Are you trying to filter out the records where status='PASS'. This will help               
 select * from (
SELECT * , 
CASE 
 WHEN val > 3 THEN 'PASS' 
 ELSE 'FAIL' 
END as Status
FROM TABLE)a
WHERE Status = 'PASS'

Comment: "_it doesn't seem to work that way_" So how **does** it work?? Show output and explain why it's wrong, or quote the error you received.

Comment: just added the error as well @underscore_d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is oracle: There are 2 things that break this query.

- It's possible to  do `SELECT *` to get all columns, but not to do `SELECT *, <some other column>`. That will raise an ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected. The workaround is to alias the table and the "*" like this `SELECT t.*, t.<some other column>`
- In the `WHERE` clause table columns or functions can be referenced, not aliases of columns that are in the `SELECT`clause. The `WHERE Status = 'PASS'` fails because "Status" is an alias, not a column.

Taking both those into account, the query becomes:

```
WITH StatusTable(id, val) AS
(
SELECT 1,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1 FROM DUAL 
) 
SELECT 
  t.* , 
  CASE 
   WHEN t.val > 3 THEN 'PASS' 
   ELSE 'FAIL' 
  END as Status
FROM StatusTable t
WHERE
  CASE 
   WHEN t.val > 3 THEN 'PASS' 
   ELSE 'FAIL' 
  END = 'PASS';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not answering directly your question but seems you want all line where val > 3
Why do you need to use 'Fail' and 'Pass' ?

```sql
SELECT Id, Val
FROM StatusTable
WHERE Val > 3
```

should give you the same result as with other suggested query

If you need a column with 'Pass', you can add it manually:

```sql
SELECT Id, Val, 'Pass'
FROM StatusTable
WHERE Val > 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing from clause in your query

```
SELECT * , 
CASE 
 WHEN val > 3 THEN 'PASS' 
 ELSE 'FAIL' 
END as Status
FROM Table_Name
WHERE Status = 'PASS'
```

Comment: The OP has just edited to add that into their code, so presumably it's not the cause, but who would know when they didn't explain _how_ "it doesn't seem to work"...?

Comment: Did you ... test this at all ?